# Localization not working in frame in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

In my Silverlight Application i have main page inside that page i have 6 Buttons (Page1,page2,Back,Forward,en-US,ja-JP).

In MainPage frame  load page 1 in that Page 1 TextBox binded with  property then i load Page 2 and change language to Ja-Jp and click Selected Back Button for Page1 but Language not changed in page1 textbox here is that code.Please help me to solve this Problem

```
        TextBox     Text="{Binding ElementName=page1,Path=MyLanguage.IetfLanguageTag, Mode=TwoWay}" 
   public XmlLanguage MyLanguage
    {
        get { return (XmlLanguage)GetValue(MyLanguageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyLanguageProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyLanguageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyLanguage", typeof(XmlLanguage), typeof(Page1), new PropertyMetadata(null, change));
    private static void change(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var update = d as Page1;
        update.languageChangeText.Text = ((System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage)(e.NewValue)).IetfLanguageTag.ToString();
    }

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        binding.Source = this;
        //binding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() { Mode = RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, AncestorType = typeof(ContentControl), AncestorLevel = 1 };
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Language");
        binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        this.SetBinding(Page2.MyLanguageProperty, binding);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is correct, except for your Binding Path

*binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Language");* should be

```
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("MyLanguage");
```